# Classes for Java snake game aren't compiling

Tags: java

Please find attached some of the source code for a game of snake I'm trying to create:

```
package Snake;

import java.awt.*;
import Snake.GameBoard.*;

public enum TileType {
  SNAKE(Color.GREEN),
  FRUIT(Color.RED),
  EMPTY(null),

  private Color tileColor;

  private TileType(Color color) {
    this.tileColor = color;
  }

  // @ return

  public Color getColor() {
    return tileColor;
  }

  private TileType[] tiles;

  public void GameBoard() {
    tiles = new TileType[MAP_SIZE * MAP_SIZE];
    resetBoard();
  }

  //  Reset all of the tiles to EMPTY.

  public void resetBoard() {
    for(int i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
      tiles[i] = TileType.EMPTY;
    }
  }

  // @ param x The x coordinate of the tile.
  // @ param y The y coordinate of the tile.
  // @ return The type of tile.

  public TileType getTile(int x, int y) {
    return tiles[y * MAP_SIZE + x];
  }

  /**
   * Draws the game board.
   * @param g The graphics object to draw to.
   */
  public void draw(Graphics2D g) {

    //Set the color of the tile to the snake color.
    g.setColor(TileType.SNAKE.getColor());

    //Loop through all of the tiles.
    for(int i = 0; i < MAP_SIZE * MAP_SIZE; i++) {

      //Calculate the x and y coordinates of the tile.
      int x = i % MAP_SIZE;
      int y = i / MAP_SIZE;

      //If the tile is empty, so there is no need to render it.
      if(tiles[i].equals(TileType.EMPTY)) {
        continue;
      }

      //If the tile is fruit, we set the color to red before rendering it.
      if(tiles[i].equals(TileType.FRUIT)) {
        g.setColor(TileType.FRUIT.getColor());
        g.fillOval(x * TILE_SIZE + 4, y * TILE_SIZE + 4, TILE_SIZE - 8, TILE_SIZE - 8);
        g.setColor(TileType.SNAKE.getColor());
      } else {
        g.fillRect(x * TILE_SIZE + 1, y * TILE_SIZE + 1, TILE_SIZE - 2, TILE_SIZE - 2);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

A lot of this works fine.  However, where it says 'private Color tileColor;', I'm getting 'I'm getting 'Syntax error on token tileColor', please delete token' but when I delete this it causes even more reds on my IDE (I'm using Eclipse).

Also, whenever MAP_SIZE and TILE_SIZE appear, it says they cannot be resolved to a variable, despite the fact they are present in the following class:

package Snake;

```
public class GameBoard {
  public static final int TILE_SIZE = 25;
  public static final int MAP_SIZE = 20;
}
```

within the same package, and should therefore be easy for the compiler to find.

Comment: It seems `TILE_SIZE` and `MAP_SIZE` are in a different class (`GameBoard`). Try `GameBoard.TILE_SIZE` and `GameBoard.MAP_SIZE`.

Comment: Try changing `EMPTY(null),` to `EMPTY(null);` (note the change from comma to semicolon).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a semi-colon here:

```
SNAKE(Color.GREEN),
FRUIT(Color.RED),
EMPTY(null); <--
```

This is required for `enums` that contain more than simply the constant definitions. From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

> when there are fields and methods, the list of enum constants must end with a semicolon.

---

`MAP_SIZE` and `TILE_SIZE` cannot be resolved as they exist in a different class, `GameBoard`. Here are 2 options:

- Use the qualified names, i.e. `GameBoard.MAP_SIZE` & `GameBoard.TILE_SIZE`

*or*

- As `enums` can implement interfaces: Make `GameBoard` an *interface* and *implement* the interface. The variables will then become member variables.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting MAP_SIZE and TILE_SIZE can't be resolved  to a variable.  How on earth do I sort this please?

Comment: You need to put their class name before them like so:
    GameBoard.MAP_SIZE

Comment: Ok I've just tried 'public enum TileType implements GameBoard {'.  I have now made GameBoard an interface, and it says 'the type GameBoard cannot be a superinterface of TileType; a super interface must be an interface'.  Is there any way round this?  Or am I misunderstanding what you suggested?

Comment: I'm asking because the interface idea is easier than systematically altering every time MAP_SIZE and TILE_SIZE come up.

Comment: You forgot to declare `GameBoard` as in interface: `public interface GameBoard {`...

Comment: I have done that, as in GameBoard is now:package Snake;

public interface GameBoard {

 public static final int TILE_SIZE = 25;
 public static final int MAP_SIZE = 20;
 
}, and TileType starts off with import java.awt.*;
import Snake.GameBoard.*;

public enum TileType implements GameBoard {

 SNAKE(Color.GREEN),
 FRUIT(Color.RED),
 EMPTY(null);

Comment: Sorry for the lack of formatting.  Am I still doing something wrong?  Sorry for the extra questions.

Comment: Looks ok, try cleaning your project & rebuilding...you may still be referring to the old `GameBoard` class.

Comment: Yep, I cleaned it, then closed and re-opened Eclipse, that's done the trick :).  Many thanks.